# Accessing previously-logged in user data through app

Tags: php, facebook, authentication

Let's say I've got an app where I've stored users' Facebook ID numbers after they've approved the app (so that they can access their own personal app page). Now I want to store users' birthdays in my app, so that they can get a birthday notification on their personal app page. Assume that users have already given my app permission to access their birthdays.

Is there any way for my app to automatically query Facebook using a user's ID#, get the user's birthday, and then update our app database with the user's birthday WITHOUT requiring them to manually log in and update the app? Again, the user has given the app permission to access birthdays, so I'm not asking for any new permissions. I just would prefer to avoid having to go back and ask all the app users to do something (particularly when they've already given our app permission to access that info).

I'm just not seeing any way to authenticate the app to get extended information on the user without having the user log in again and manually update the app. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thankfully, an application can not decide to *take* permissions from a user without asking.  A user will **always** have to *grant* an application permissions.  
An alternative would be on initial authentication, to request the `email` and `user_birthday` permissions, store that data in your database and once a day (possible initiated by a cron job) send emails programatically to the users on the day of their birth. 
Don't forget to send them some cake too ;)

[image]
<sub>(source: [funnycakepics.com](http://www.funnycakepics.com/pictures/Nerd_Cake542.jpg))</sub>

Comment: But if the user has already given the app permission to access their birthday info, it wouldn't be _taking_ permissions, would it? Or is Facebook set up so that _anytime_ an app is dealing with a user's info, whether they've given the app permission or not, the user MUST log in and give permissions?

Comment: Yes - the user must be logged in (or you must have a valid access token).  The `offline_access` permission (which would have been perfect for your scenario) [has been deprecated](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/).  Users must be actively using your application for it to access their data.